# Column Message_Parameters in Table Core_Email_Queue

Tags: magento-1.9, email, messages

May I know what is the data format in that column? It doesn't look like JSON.

For example:

```
a:7:{s:7:"subject";s:34:"Online Shop: New Order # 100000018";s:17:"return_path_email";N;s:8:"is_plain";b:0;s:10:"from_email";s:22:"foobar@example.com";s:9:"from_name";s:5:"Sales";s:8:"reply_to";N;s:9:"return_to";N;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's serialized.
To transform it into an array use `unserialize($value)`.